# Using data.table to calculate a function which depends on many columns

Tags: r, data.table

There are many posts which discuss applying a function over many columns when using data.table.  However I need to calculate a function which depends on many columns.  As an example:

```
# Create a data table with 26 columns.  Variable names are var1, ..., var 26
data.mat = matrix(sample(letters, 26*26, replace=TRUE),ncol=26)
colnames(data.mat) = paste("var",1:26,sep="")
data.dt <- data.table(data.mat)
```

Now, say I would like to count the number of 'a's in columns 5,6,7  and 8. 
I cannot see how to do this with SDcols and end up doing:

```
data.dt[,numberOfAs := (var5=='a')+(var6=='a')+(var7=='a')+(var7=='a')]
```

Which is very tedious.  Is there a more sensible way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like your data may be in the wrong shape (wide vs long). Are you sure this is the best structure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really suggest going through the [vignettes linked here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944). Section 2e from the [Introduction to data.table vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html) explains `.SD` and `.SDcols`.

`.SD` is just a data.table containing the data for current group. And `.SDcols` tells the columns `.SD` should have. A useful way is to use `print` to see the content.

```
# .SD contains cols 5:8
data.dt[, print(.SD), .SDcols=5:8]
```

Since there is no `by` here, `.SD` contains all the rows of `data.dt`, corresponding to the columns specified in `.SDcols`.

---

Once you understand this, the task reduces to your knowledge of base R really. You can accomplish this in more than one way.

```
data.dt[, numberOfAs := rowSums(.SD == "a"), .SDcols=5:8]
```

We return a logical matrix by comparing all the columns in `.SD` to *"a"*. And then use `rowSums` to sum them up.

Another way using `Reduce`:

```
data.dt[, numberOfAs := Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x == "a")), .SDcols=5:8]
```